# Simulating a click in web performance tests

Tags: tools, performance, web-application, visualstudio

I am working with web-test in visual studio test system, without writing a code test, is there a way to invoke a click on a link/button/submit item? I am thinking of doing this by adding a request in the gui editor but can't for the life of me figure out if it's possible or how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click I was simulating had a js onclick event to change the page, obviously vsts doesn't support javascript. So to get round this I removed the request to click and then added a get request which mimic'd what the onclick event was trying to achieve.